# Output path of OCaml executable in OASIS

Tags: ocaml, oasis

I'm trying to specify executables in my _oasis configuration. This works fine so far, and a link to the compiled binary is created in the root directory of my _oasis configuration. However, I would rather have the binary (link) be created in the subdirectory ./bin - is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
PostBuildCommand: mv -L main.native bin/main.native
```

You can find it [here](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/MANUAL.html#package).